# Issue with WiFi and MacBook Pro when connected to external Monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, network, display, wifi

I have recently been having issues with my WiFi connection (on both 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz networks) when my laptop is in clamshell mode and connected to an external 4k monitor. I use a USB-C to HDMI adapter (from Uni). From what I've read, it may be caused by interference created by my adapter (?) or something of the sort, and one solution I have tried to do is to wrap my adapter with aluminum foil (as suggested by some YouTube videos online). None of this appears to have any sort of effect. There are a few rare times I have successfully been able to maintain a connection, but the only thing that seems different in those situations are the position of the HDMI cable and adapter. I still don't have any idea as to what positions clearly allow for a connection, and those that do not.

I should note that I only have these connection issues when I solely use the external monitor. If I connect my device to the monitor, and use the laptop's built-in screen as well as the external monitor, the wifi works perfectly fine.

More information on my system:

**Hardware: 2.2 GHz Intel Core i7, 16 GB 2400 MHz DDR4, Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB, Radeon Pro 555X**

How exactly should I resolve this issue?

Comment: Can I suggest you [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/365034/edit) your question to include the exact details of the hardware involved (e.g. the external monitor, the MBP itself, and even the adapter if possible). Also, it'd be good to know *how* you're using your MBP when connected to the external monitor (e.g. is it being used in [closed-clamshell mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201834), or are you using both screens)?

Comment: I have this exact problem, did you find a way to resolve this?

Comment: If you don't use a 4K monitor. It works fine with a 1080p one. I also did have mixed luck with wrapping with aluminium foil, though I'm not quite sure if that actually did anything, or if I perceived it to.

Comment: I have this problem as well, but with an older 2015 MBP and a 1080p monitor and using a mini-Display port to DVI adapter. Strangely this started five days ago for me and was never an issue in 1.5 years before with same monitor, same adapter and same MBP